# Refresh a container panel while clicking the pager numbers

Tags: xpages

I have a data table inside a tabbed panel. The pager control for this data table is not refreshing itself no matter if the pager is inside the tabbed panel or outside. But the data table is advancing to the next page(s) without problem. Has anyone faced this issue? Here is a sample code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel1">
<xp:this.selectedTab><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.selectedTab?viewScope.selectedTab:"tabPanel1"}]]></xp:this.selectedTab>
    <xp:pager layout="Previous Group Next" partialExecute="true"
        partialRefresh="true" for="dataTable1" id="pager1">
    </xp:pager>
    <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab 1" id="tabPanel1">
        <xp:dataTable id="dataTable1" rows="2" indexVar="i">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:["1","2","3","4","5","6"]}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:column id="column1">
                <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:i}">
                </xp:text>
            </xp:column>
        </xp:dataTable>
    </xp:tabPanel>
    <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab 2" id="tabPanel2"></xp:tabPanel>
    <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab 3" id="tabPanel3"></xp:tabPanel>
    <xp:tabPanel label="New Tab 4" id="tabPanel4"></xp:tabPanel>
</xp:tabbedPanel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set partialRefresh="false" then the pager will refresh along with all other elements on the page.

Comment: I know that, but I don't want the whole page to refresh. With the partialRefresh set to false, it will refresh the pager if the data table is not inside the tabbed panel.

Comment: Your pager was added independently of the data table. Did you try removing that and adding the standard data table pager in the header?  Everything should work fine then.

Comment: That was it Mike. I missed the xp:key. Thanks for pointing that out.